# Azure Insights: tracking custom property through the chain of function executions

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have Azure **Function1->Function2->Service** flow of calls in my Azure app. There are multiple concurrent calls of Function1 and each could be identified by some unique input Document Id. I wonder how in c# code I can set something in Azure Insight context to that document id in the beginning of Funciton1, so that any `[traces]` or `[exceptions]` or `[dependencies]` logged to Azure Insights in any of the follow up calls contains the document id. I noticed all of them have `customDimension` nested list of properties, so maybe somehow add one more property to there. Also if Function1 runs multiple times in parallel, I do not want these document id to be mixed up.

Goal is to be able to track this document id in all kinds of logs with min amount of additional c# code, avoid passing the document id from function to other functions and other services, so looking into any type of log (wheatear it's traces or exceptions or other) I'm able to immediately identify document the execution belonged to. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To attach a custom property to all logs whithin an azure function is not that diffucult, one could simply use a [telemetry initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#itelemetryprocessor-and-itelemetryinitializer) to do that:

```cs
    public class TelemetryEnrichment : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (!(telemetry is ISupportProperties item)) return;

            // Demonstrate static property
            item.Properties["Environment"] = "Production";
        }
    }
```

If it is an http triggered function you can enricht the request telemetry like this:

```cs
var requestTelemetry = req.HttpContext.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("aProp", "aValue");
```

You also want to have to property logged by other functions that are called by the entry function. This is not easy doable: you will need to pass the id to the other function manually, for example by passing it using the url of that function.

However, if you have to Id attached to the logs of the entry function you can easily create a query to correlate the logs. Based on the [operation id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#data-model-for-telemetry-correlation) you can get the whole picture of the communication flow between the functions and services, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/transaction-diagnostics#transaction-diagnostics-experience):

[image]

That way, you do not need to include the Id as a custom property to each and every telemetry item.

Comment: Peter, thank you for your answer. However there are couple of problems in applying this approach to my situation which I do not know how to overcome: 1) ITelemetryInitializer does not work for me since I need to record Function input parameter (doc id, unique for each Function call). 2) `Properties` collection is marked by [Obsolete]. If I try to search what it's replaced by it brings me to the same ITelemetryInitializer  which I can't pass input parameter to. 3) it's durable function triggered by time trigger function that spins off other multiple concurrent functions which I want to track

Comment: @YMC I will address those issue later, I don't see any that cannot be solved but answering on my phone is not going to work:-)